# Joint uniform distribution, change of variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

$(X,Y)$ are uniformly distributed on the unit disk $D$. Their joint density is $f_{(X,Y)}(x,y)=\frac{1}{\pi}\mathbb{1}_D$. If we change to polar coordinates, meaning $(X,Y)=(R\cos(\theta),R\sin(\theta)),$ what would the joint distribution of $(R,\theta)$ be?
The change of variables leads to $R=\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$, $\theta=\tan^{-1}(\frac{Y}{X})$, where $R\in[0,1], \theta\in[-\pi,\pi].$
For an arbitrary borel function $g$, we calculate  $$\mathbb{E}[g(R,\theta)] = \int_{[0,1]\times[-\pi,\pi]} g\Bigl(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}, \arctan(y/x)\Bigr)\frac{r}{\pi}drdt$$where $\frac{1}{\pi}$ is the constant from the joint density of $(X,Y)$, and the term $r$ comes from the determinant of the Jacobian matrix:$$ |J|=\det\begin{pmatrix}\cos(\theta) & -R\sin(\theta)\\ \sin(\theta) & R\cos(\theta)   \end{pmatrix} = R  $$Therefore $f_{(R,\theta)}(r,t)=\frac{r}{\pi}.$ Is this correct, and if so, does this mean that $(R,\theta)$ are independent? Would the probability that a point is within a certain radius just be the integral of the joint density over $[0,R]\times[-\pi,\pi]$ instead of $[0,1]\times[-\pi,\pi]$? Thanks for the help!

Comment: "Is this correct?" - yes, you have the correct formula and the correct way to get the formula.

"does this mean that  and  are independent" - yes, you can use the conditions "P(x|y) = P(x)" and the formula you have to check that they are independent.

"Would the probability that a point is within a certain radius just be the integral of the joint density over [0,]×[−,]?" - yes, you integrate density times the indicator functions, and the indicator function is one for x<R and zero for x>R, so you end up with the integral of density functions for area x< R, which is [0,]×[−,]

Comment: @IBazhov thank you for taking the time!